# join method not working on array JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I created this code that I draw an array, but today I'll explain what is this code because the problem is another. 
I run a processing del'array "elaborazione", the problem is that when I want to remove the commas, using the join method does not work, the text remains the commas, how is it possible? What is wrong with this code?

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{
   var opt = new Option();
   var elaborazione = v[i].split(";");
   elaborazione.splice(2,2);
   elaborazione.join(" ");
   alert("elaborazione => " + elaborazione);
   opt.innerHTML = elaborazione;
   select.add(opt);
}
```

Comment: join method doesn't change the variable but "returns" the joined string. assign the returned value to elaborazione.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

> The join() method joins all elements of an array into a string.

You need to save the joined string in `elaborazione` variable.

Use

```
elaborazione = elaborazione.join(" ");
```